# Difference between Airflow environment variable and secret environment variable

Tags: airflow

What is the difference between Airflow environment variable (Eg. `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN`) and a secret environment variable (`AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_SECRET`)?

Answer (score 1):

**AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN**
You are supplying the connection information directly.

**AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_SECRET**
This allows you to provide the name of a secret which contains your connection information.

> This will retrieve config option from Secret Backends e.g Hashicorp Vault. See Secrets Backends for more details.

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/set-config.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set Airflow configs containing Sensitive data using either the command to run passed via Environment Variable (`AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_CMD`) or using Airflow Secrets (e.g `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_SECRET`).

For example, if you are using Hashicorp Vault as Airflow Secert's Backend ([docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.12/howto/use-alternative-secrets-backend.html#hashicorp-vault-secrets-backend)):

You can add the secret value in Vault as follows:

```
❯ vault kv put secret/config/sql_alchemy_conn value=sqlite:////Users/airflow/airflow/airflow.db
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2020-11-20T20:05:21.517705Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1
```

and set the following environment Variables:

```
❯ env | grep AIRFLOW
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_SECRET=sql_alchemy_conn
AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND=airflow.contrib.secrets.hashicorp_vault.VaultBackend
AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS='{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8200","auth_type":"token", "token": "s.OddaHiiDdddpW6gNnqtd2lJ"}'
```

This way you don't need to expose your secrets in `airflow.cfg` file.